# How can I apply 2 qubit pauli operator error instead of CNOT operator in stim code?

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, stim

Currently I am building up quantum error correction code with stim code.

According to this paper [https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.86.032324], I need to make an error channel that includes CNOT operators and 2 qubit Pauli operator set.

for example, Attempting to perform CNOT operator, but instead appling `X_1 X_2` operator with some probability p.

Is there any way I can make this kind of error channel in stim code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CORRELATED_ERROR`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.8-Gate-Reference#CORRELATED_ERROR) to introduce probabilistic Pauli products.

```
CNOT 0 1
CORRELATED_ERROR(0.001) X0 X1
```

You can also use [`DEPOLARIZE2`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.8-Gate-Reference#DEPOLARIZE2), which includes equal portions of all 15 possible two qubit Pauli errors, and [`PAULI_CHANNEL_2`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.8-Gate-Reference#PAULI_CHANNEL_2), which lets you specify 15 float parameters one for each of the two qubit Pauli error cases.

Note that you can't apply these errors *instead of* a CNOT. Stim doesn't support conditional or probabilistic Clifford operations. You can only apply them *in addition to* a CNOT. This is compatible with the paper you cited; I'm not sure where you got the idea you needed to not do the CNOT instead of perturb the CNOT.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was informative. The paper says, attempting to perform a measure qubit-data qubit CNOT, but instead performing one of the two-qubit operations I ⊗ X, I⊗Y, I⊗Z, X⊗I, X⊗X, X⊗Y, X⊗Z, Y⊗I, Y⊗X, Y⊗Y, Y⊗Z, Z⊗I, Z⊗X, Z⊗Y, or Z⊗Z each with probability p/15. So I thought this means an error channel that includes CNOT operators and 2 qubit Pauli operator set. But like you mentioned, Maybe I will try to perturb the CNOT.

Comment: @YounghunKim That error you described from the paper is a `DEPOLARIZE2(p)` error.